# why isn't a function executing after a specific function

Tags: c++, function, methods

In my code the temp1print() function is executing when placed before the print() function but isn't executing when placed after the print() function.

The following program is to insert data at the end in a linked list.
I would like to know why the temp1Print() function is not executing when placed after the print() function.

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
}Node;

struct Node* head;
struct Node* temp1;

struct Node* Insert(struct Node* head,int data){

    temp1 = head;
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if(head == NULL){
        head = temp;
        printf("head after inserting %d is %d\n",temp->data,head);
        printf("temp1 after inserting %d is %d\n",temp->data,temp1);
        return head;
    }
    else{
        while(temp1->next!=NULL){
            temp1 = temp1->next;
        }
        temp1->next = temp;
        printf("temp1 after inserting %d is %d\n",temp->data,temp1);
        printf("temp1->data=%d temp1->next=%d\n\n",temp1->data,temp1->next);
        return head;
    }
}


void print(Node* head){
    Node* temp = head;
    printf("head = %d\n",head);
    while(temp!=NULL){
        printf("%d ",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("%d",temp->data);
}


void temp1Print(){
    printf("temp1 = %d\n",temp1);
}

int main(){

    head = NULL;
    head = Insert(head,2);
    head = Insert(head,4);
    head = Insert(head,6);
    head = Insert(head,8);
    temp1Print(); //This function is working when placed before the print function
    print(head);
    temp1Print();  //Why isn't this function working when placed after the print function?
}
```

Comment: `printf("temp1 = %d\n",temp1)` is undefined behavior.  `temp1` is not an `int`.

Comment: @NathanOliver   then why does it work before the print() function?

Comment: It's undefined behavior.  It may work, it may not, it may work and then not.  It might not work and then work.  You've violated the code contract so any outcome is "correct".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `print` function, your last `printf("%d",temp->data);` is called when `temp` pointer is `NULL`. This means that you're dereferencing an invalid pointer which in result cause undefined behaviour.